# nodemcu + esp8266 + hc-sr04 - tmr.now() difference is incorrect

Tags: lua, nodemcu, esp8266

i've started using nodemcu on esp8266.
I've connected esp with hc-sr04 (ultrasound sensor for distance measurement).
hc-sr04 need to receive high state for trig pin for 10us. After that hc send high state of echo pin. The time of the high state from echo pin can be different (depends of distance). The time is counted in us.
The problem is that this time from echo pin is incorrect (IMHO). I'm not sure but is this possible that tmr. from nodemcu is not as precise as it should? And why there is so big difference between times in each loop?

My code and below you will find time printings from code:

```
gpio.write(3,gpio.LOW)
gpio.mode(3,gpio.OUTPUT)

gpio.write(4,gpio.LOW)
gpio.mode(4,gpio.INT)


time=0
flag=0
i=1

function startDis(level)
    time=tmr.now()
end    

function endDis(level)
    time=tmr.now()-time
    flag=0
end    

function trigger()
    gpio.write(3,gpio.HIGH)
    tmr.delay(10)
    gpio.write(3,gpio.LOW)
    flag=1
end

gpio.trig(4,'up',startDis)
gpio.trig(4,'down',endDis)
```

// ---------THIS PART HAS BEEN CHANGED--------

```
while i<10 do
    if flag==0 then
        trigger()
    end
    tmr.delay(1000000)
    print(time)
    i=i+1
end
```

//--------------- TO ------------

```
tmr.alarm(0,2000,1,function()
    print(time)
    print(i)
    if flag==0 then
        trigger()
    end
    i=i+1
    if i==10 then tmr.stop(0) end
end)
```

Code prints:

```
0
440184038
1999856
442183990
4000221
444184055
6000175
446184287
7999686
```

Thanks for clues and solutions.

Comment: Have a read of [When and why should I avoid using tmr.delay()?](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=nodemcu-unofficial-faq#when_and_why_should_i_avoid_using_tmrdelay)

Comment: @TerryE I've read that and I made few changes. No more delay in loop (only for lifting pin for 10us). I've used tmr.alarm instead of that. As you notice the times are still strange.

Answer (score 0):

Petre, I'll do this as an answer because it doesn't fit into a quick comment. :(

You need to read some of the other discussion in the FAQ on how the overall SDK schedules tasks.  You are assuming in your code that something like this happens:

```
<every 2mSec>
print(time)
print(i)
if flag==0 then
    gpio.write(3,gpio.HIGH)
        time=tmr.now()
    tmr.delay(10)
    gpio.write(3,gpio.LOW)
        time=tmr.now()-time
        flag=0
    flag=1
end
i=i+1
if i==10 then tmr.stop(0) end
```

where in in reality what happens is closer to:

```
<every 2mSec task starts>
print(time)
print(i)
if flag==0 then
    gpio.write(3,gpio.HIGH)
        <H/W interupts calls low level GPIO which books up callback> 
        time=tmr.now()
    tmr.delay(10)
        <H/W interupts calls low level GPIO which books down callback> 
    gpio.write(3,gpio.LOW)
    flag=1
end
i=i+1
if i==10 then tmr.stop(0) end
<task ends>
<possible TCP and other tasks run>
<up trigger is delivered>
        time=tmr.now()
<task ends>
<possible TCP and other tasks run>
<down trigger is delivered>
        time=tmr.now()-time
        flag=0    
<task ends>
```

The Esp8266 SDK is not a real Real Time O/S; it is event driven.  It's your mindset that needs to get reorientated.

Using the `tmr.delay()` this way is the correct use, but you need HW test tools such as an oscilloscope or logic analyser to check what the actual delay is because you need to add in the time to process the Lua instructions. 
Or even put the tmr.now() calls inline.

The real usecase for the trigger is where you have an input connected to a sensor such as a mechanical open/close detector and this avoids the need to poll it.